# SharePoint Online Retention Policy Timer Job

Tags: sharepoint-online, information-management, retention

I have an SPO library with a Retention Policy attached for archiving items over 3 months old. The policy is attached to the location, not the content type, and is set to run when a field (Arrival Date) is +3 months, whereupon it engages a workflow which copies the item to another library, then deletes the original.

My question is: how can I tell when the timer job that kicks off the retention steps has run? I seem to remember it's about once a week per site collection, but need to know exactly how to get this for support documentation and handover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the thing I'd forgot about for this.

Open the site collection in Designer, then go to Site Options. There are two properties - dlc_PolicyUpdateLastRun and dlc_RouterJobLastRun - which are for the last run of the Retention and Expiration jobs respectively.

More info here - http://www.pbnet.ro/?p=557

Answer (score 0):

from what I know - you can't really tell this in SPO. At one point it took me 3 weeks to get the retention policy to "kick in", so I am not sure if you can really see when that happens.